# How to use glyphicons in bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have already used glyphicons in bootstrap 2.3 but now I have upgraded to bootstrap 3.0. Now, I am unable to use the icon property.

In bootstrap 2.3, below tag is working

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

In bootstrap 3.0, it's not working.

Comment: Hi all,I have done the same and followed up the structure but not getting the correct glyphicon...An unidentified 0101 type image is shown instead of glyphicon

Comment: Thanks,actually the problem was that i was using .less file directly without converting it to css...oops

Comment: For version 3.0.0, it **breaks** by defaults. Tried a few `solutions`, no one works for me.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue using .less file directly using less.js. Of course, in that situation, I would also like to see it work

Answer (score 108):

The icons (glyphicons) are now contained in a [separate css file..](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/).

The markup has changed to:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
```

or

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

Here is a helpful list of changes for Bootstrap 3: http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Comment: Hi all,I have done the same and followed up the structure but not getting the correct glyphicon...An unidentified 0101 type image is shown instead of glyphicon

Comment: Can you show your code that include the bootstrap and glyphicons CSS? Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Just make sure you're including the glyphicons.css correctly. It should work fine: http://bootply.com/61521

Comment: i have added this properly...the structure is css/fonts/....,css/less/...,css/bootstrap.min.css and in bootstrap.min.css i have included @import "less/bootstrap-glyphicons.less";

Comment: Thanks,actually the problem was that i was using .less file directly without converting it to css...oops

Comment: This was extremely helpful! The part that solved my issue was adding the glyphicon class before the glyphicon-(icon) class. I didn't know they had to have both but now I do!

Comment: The separate css file link seems to be broken.

Comment: It was only relevant for Bootstrap 3.0.. releases after 3.1 included the glyphicons in the CSS again.

Answer (score 29):

There you go:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
```

**More information:**

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Btw. you can use this [conversion tool](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/), this will also update the code for the icons:

Comment: Bootply Migration save a lot of time converting code to TWB 3. Very useful, @Michael / Buhake-Sindi.

Answer (score 19):

If yout download a customized bootstrap 3 distro you must:

1. Download the full distro from 
   https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.0.0.zip
2. Uncompress and upload the entire folder called `fonts` to your bootstrap directory.  Put together with the other folders "css, js".

Example Before:

```
\css
\js
index.html
```

Example After Upload:

```
\css
\fonts
\js
index.html
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine (Jan 2016). Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

If you're using less , and it's not loading the icons font you must  check out the font path
go to the file **variable.less** and change the **@icon-font-path** path , that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 3 requires span tag not i

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>`
```

Answer (score 3):

Include the fonts Copy over all the font files to a /fonts directory near your CSS.

1. Include the CSS or LESS You have two options for enabling the fonts
   in your project: vanilla CSS or source LESS. For vanilla CSS, just
   include the compiled CSS file from the **/css** in the repository.
2. For LESS, copy over the **.less** files from **/less** into your existing
   Bootstrap directory. Then import it into **bootstrap.less** via **@import
   "bootstrap-glyphicons.less";**. Recompile when ready.
3. Add some icons! After you've added the fonts and CSS, you can get to
   using the icons. For example, `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>`

[source](http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Hi all,I have done the same and followed up the structure but not getting the correct glyphicon...An unidentified 0101 type image is shown instead of glyphicon

Answer (score 3):

If you are using grunt to build your application, it's possible that during build the paths change. In this case you need to modify your grunt file like this:

```
copy: {
        main: {
            files: [{
                src: ['fonts/**'],
                dest: 'dist/fonts/',
                filter: 'isFile',
                expand: true,
                flatten: true
            }, {
                src: ['bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**'],
                dest: 'dist/css/',
                filter: 'isFile',
                expand: true,
                flatten: false
            }]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Download all files from bootstrap and then include this css

```
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
            src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
        }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. It contains many examples which will be useful in understanding.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.