# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons error

Tags: css, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to upgrade from Bootstrap2 to Bootstrap3. Everything works so far, except the Glyphicons: a square is displayed instead of the icon: [image]

I'm using Symfony2. This is how I call Bootstrap CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" type="text/css" />
```

This is how I call the glyphicons:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

My file structure is as follows:

- /web

  - /css

    - bootstrap.css
  - /fonts

    - the 4 glyphicons files

It seems that this is a common problem (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-not-working), [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205738/how-to-use-glyphicons-in-bootstrap-3-0) or [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603355/twitter-bootstrap-3-icon-displaying-a-square/18777559) for example), but none of the solution found there solved my problem.

I downloaded the files from bootstrap website, not from the customizer.
Moreover, I made a test with the following file structure (in a complete different folder but with the same Bootstrap files), found on one of those topics:

- /test

  - /css

    - bootstrap.css
  - /fonts

    - the 4 glyphicons files
  - index.html

Index.html beeing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta chaset="utf-8">
    <title>Test icons</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

And this test works perfectly, so the glyphicons files are not corrupted.

The charset of my real site is UTF-8 as well.

I checked the bootstrap.css file and the glyphicons reference seems OK:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}

.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

So I guess the way I call the CSS "modifies" its path which is consequently different from the glyphicons path, which is the icons are not found.

How should I call the CSS or modify the src: url('????????/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'); to have the proper link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check what you have exluded /fonts path in `security.yml`

```
security:
    firewalls:
        assets:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js|fonts)/
            security: false
```

What happens if you directly access font(*yourhost.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff*)? Also check firebug or chrome inspector for errors in network tab.

Comment: I added the lines in 'security.yml' as you said. I can see the content of 'yourhost.com/fonts/' but 'yourhost.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff' is 403 forbidden. Firebug says the same thing (403 Forbidden in Network/Fonts tab for glyph...woff and glyph...ttf). I have a WAMP system and I checked files permissions and all users have read/write/execute rights on all 4 files. But this is now clear that the problem is somewhere in this area!

Comment: I "shaked" those files in all ways I could and I managed to get the thing work... I believe the problem was due to the fact that **the 4 files were encrypted**. I removed that and now it's ok. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Move your fonts directory into the css directory.
Bootstrap looks for fonts in that directory.
Request:
..yoursite/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff in example