# Bootstrap 3 glyphicon is not displayed correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<a class="btn btn-default" id="exportdata" href="#"><i class="glyphicon-export"></i></a>
```

On Chrome 34 the glyphicon shows a "square"

On IE 11 the glyphicon shows nothing

On FF 28 the glyphicon shows an odd icon with numbers/chars it looks broken...

What is wrong with my hyperlink?

I know there are similar/same problems on SO. But they did not help me.

For example this one: [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156627/twitter-bootstrap-3-glyphicons-error)

Where is this security.yml file? Its not in my fonts folder!

I get this in my chrome console:

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/x-woff: "http://localhost:5264/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3".
```

Why interpreted as Font? Do I have to set something in IIS?

Comment: I think that it is just a localhost issue

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Bootstrap glyphicon not showing in Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659094/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-showing-in-form/35660280#35660280)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh dear... the answer is that the font works when I do this:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i>
```

instead of this:

```
<i class="glyphicon-export"></i>
```

one .glyphicon class was missing...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set on ISS the correct MIME type for woff resources using:

```
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
```

Comment: The error message in chrome console is gone but still the icon does not show correctly :/