# Bootstrap 3 TimePicker no glyphicons in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and setting up time/date pickers. I've setup a fiddle to show what I'm talking about [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sesellis/YcXQj/19/). When viewed in Chrome the arrows on the time picker appear without issue but in IE 11 they don't appear. I haven't tried other versions of IE yet but 11 is showing this behavior.

JS:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6' data-date-format="ddd MM/DD/YYYY">-->
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker6' data-date-format="ddd MM/DD/YYYY"/>
                <!--</div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker7'/>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I've seen some similar issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174310/bootstrap-3-glyphicon-is-not-displayed-correctly) but they don't seem applicable to my situation. Any thoughts?

Sam

Comment: 11, post edited for clarity.

Comment: The issue appears also in Firefox (version 30), so I guess this might not an IE specific issue..

Comment: I'm getting the content CSS for the glyph canceled out by something. I'm not actually seeing anything listed overriding it, but IE11 is displaying it that way (crossed out).

Comment: I see the arrows just fine. Make sure you have not triggered your browser to render in compatibility mode (just a guess) or that you somehow have not caused it to use one of the compatibility engines to render.