# How to add an image to a custom CSS button

Tags: html, css

I have the following button HTML code:

```
<button class="button" style="width: 95%;">PHYSICIANS</button>
```

It is customized by CSS3 here:

```
button {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #eee;
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 21px 34px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.21, rgb(203,203,203)), color-stop(0.58, rgb(227,226,226)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(203,203,203) 21%, rgb(227,226,226) 58%);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3) /* glass edge */, inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5) /* top highlight */, inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5) /* bottom shadow */;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
button::-moz-focus-inner, a.button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
button:hover, a.button:hover {
    background: #cbcbcb;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:active, a.button:active {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 22px 34px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Which displays the following button:

[image]

How can I modify the above code, so I can add a thumbnail image to it. Something like this:

[image]

The default image size is 260X190 but I want to size it up so it fits inside the button.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **pseudo-element** `:before` to do this.

See this working demo I made: http://jsfiddle.net/A7UsX/1/

```
button:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("http://www.wdc.com/Global/images/icons/icon_supporthelp.gif") no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

I have made a red background to show you what I did. Change the `background` to the image you would like and change the `height` and `width` to your likings.

Comment: Thank You... I will go ahead and test it out.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong but I don't see the image :/ http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwmg-ektron2-dev%3A81%2Fwmgwebsite%2FDefault.aspx

Comment: OOOOPS... It's a internal server website :/ Sorry! Here is a pastebin of what I have. On the DEV tool, I can see the stylesheet and also see the image being imported but it doesn't get shown: http://pastebin.com/KCZxmuKM

Comment: It is working. Check my edit. I have made it more clear to you by adding the image.

Comment: Weird, I used your image it's fine. The text is not vertically centered. How can I achieve that? I think something wrong with the way I am importing my image?

Comment: I changed the line from yours to `background: url("theImages/ste.png") no-repeat;` and the image disappears.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer so that we can close this topic off.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `:before` pseudo element.

```
button:before{content: ' '; display:inline-block;  position:absolute; content:url(http://lorempixel.com/25/25); }
```

I'll suggest you to use a SVG image rather than using jpg or png format. so in this case you can call the image using `background-image` and give a positioning too.

```
button:before { content:''; display:inline-block; height:1em; width:1em; 
background-image:url('images/image.svg'); background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat;  }
```

here you can check the working Demo. http://jsbin.com/damujidi/1/edit

Comment: check the other solution.. this way you can move the image as well. please replace `svg`` with jpg` or `png` what format you using..

Comment: What would be the advantage of the SVG over PNG/JPG?

Comment: SVG is scalable format. they are more sharp rather than png or JPG ..the other benefits is it won't lost quality if you scale them

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong but I don't see the image :/ http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwmg-ektron2-dev%3A81%2Fwmgwebsite%2FDefault.aspx

Comment: even I can't see the page.. this display message coming "This page can’t be displayed"

Comment: OOOOPS... It's a internal server website :/ Sorry! Here is a pastebin of what I have. On the DEV tool, I can see the stylesheet and also see the image being imported but it doesn't get shown: http://pastebin.com/KCZxmuKM

Comment: please specify the actual height and width to image not `1em`

Comment: Yes, exactly what you said :/

Comment: use the actual image `height` and `width` in CSS.

Comment: You can't see it because it's internal unfortunately but here is the code from pastebin: http://pastebin.com/nSm2AvLQ

Comment: what's the use of this class `defbtn`?

Comment: No use. I can remove it if need be. I did add the image I am using in my question, if you want to test.

Comment: I am looking at your code, really some serious problem

Comment: Ok... I am all ear to listen :)

Comment: I see you forgot to add these line in your `content: ' '; position:absolute;` in `button:before`

Comment: aaaahhhhh, it's working but now the image is centered in the button and extends out even after using width and height.

Comment: doesn't image is besides the text?

Comment: Nope. The image overlaps the text :/

Comment: share the screenshot please

Comment: I am leaving for the day... I might have it working another person's CSS but If it still gives problem I will surely post a screenshot tomorrow. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: in the meantime can you accept this answer. because example shows its works

Comment: try to remove `position:absolute;` and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `<i>` as commonly used in bootstrap [[ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205738)] [[ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273500/)].

```
<button class="button">
    <i class="btnbg"></i>PHYSICIANS
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btnbg {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgIOj.png');
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
}

.button {
    line-height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[see jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JK86L/)